# React-Native animation has a small pause

Tags: react-native

```js
 animate() {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.spinValue, {
        toValue: 360,
        duration: 1000
      })
    ).start();
  }
```

I call this function in `componentDidMount` and its clearly looping the animation however, on every loop there is a slight delay before it starts. Trying to figure out how that can just become a smooth `0 -> 360` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Easing.linear` was the solution.

```js
 animate() {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(this.spinValue, {
        fromValue:0,
        toValue: 360,
        duration: 1000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }),
      {useNativeDriver: true}
    ).start();
  }
```